# toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript

How do I make this include words from the array that has uppercase letters?

```js
const array = ["amassment", "amassments", "Amasta", "amasthenic", "amasty", "amastia", "AMAT", "Amata", "amate"]
const word = array.filter(m=> m.includes(args[0]))
const wrd = word.toLowerCase()

if(!wrd) return message.delete()

console.log(`${wrd}`)
```

When my args[0] is "am", it only sends `"amassment"`, `"amassments"`, `"amasthenic"`, `"amasty"`, `"amastia"`, `"amate"`. It doesn't include words in uppercase at all.
Even though I added the `.toLowerCase()`, I get an error `word.toLowerCase() is not a function`. I need help.

Comment: `word` is an array, which doesn't have a method called `toLowerCase`. Did you mean to use `find` instead of `filter` to define `word`? Or did you mean to apply `toLowerCase` to each of the words in the `word` array with `map`?

Comment: I changed `filter` to `find` but I still get the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call toLowerCase() inside filter function.

```
const word = array.filter(m=> m.toLowerCase().includes(args[0]))
```

If your args also needs to be lower cased and included, you can use the below approach to check

```
const word = array.filter(m=> m.match(new RegExp(args[0],"i")));
```

Comment: You might also want to convert `args[0]` to lower case